# Spring @Query with principal and ternary operator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-el, ternary

```
@Query("select p from Person p where p.id=?#{principal=='anonymousUser'?0:principal.id})")
public Person getCurrentUser();
```

This method is intended to return a current user/person or nothing (there is no user with id=0 in the database) if the user is anonymous. And it works fine in the first case, but when the user is anonymous it gives an error:

> org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set:
>   [1] [select p from Person p where p.id=?1)]

It seems it expects some parameters now, but why? Shouldn't the query be

```
select p from Person p where p.id=0
```

?

Comment: It seems it will work if you replaces `0` by `null`

Comment: Confirmed, thank you! Working code is `@Query("select p from Person p where p.id=?#{principal=='anonymousUser'?null:principal.id})")
public Person getCurrentUser();`

Comment: I added it as an answer for others to make use of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it will work if you replaces 0 by null